# How do I install Multistrap 2.1.9+ on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu

So I am trying to install Multistrap for PDEBuild but I am getting an error saying the Ubuntu default version of multistrap (2.1.6ubuntu) is less than the required (2.1.9+). Anyone know how I install the newer version? I tried adding the lenny Debian repo but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you find the answer?  Looking at this right now too.  Will report if I get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to install pbuilder, download multistrap source package from [here](https://launchpad.net/debian/experimental/+source/multistrap/2.1.9) (both the .dsc and .tar.gz), and build the package:

```
sudo apt-get install pbuilder
mkdir -p /tmp/build_multistrap && cd /tmp/build_multistrap
wget https://launchpad.net/debian/experimental/+source/multistrap/2.1.9/+files/multistrap_2.1.9.dsc https://launchpad.net/debian/experimental/+source/multistrap/2.1.9/+files/multistrap_2.1.9.tar.gz
sudo pbuilder build multistrap_2.1.9.dsc
cd /var/cache/pbuilder/result
sudo dpkg -i multistrap_2.1.9_all.deb 
rm -rf /tmp/build_multistrap
```